# Why __path__[0] in reqular packages is the only index searched?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I create a regular package in Python I get an object with `__path__` method which is considered a special type of module according to Python documentation. My question is why in `pack.__path__` list only the first item is searched and the others are omitted and why it's a list rather than a normal string since the other items aren't scanned ?

Example: 
Suppose we have a directory names C:\code which contains a package name pkg. and another path which contains spam.py:

```
    C\
     pkg\                #Regular package
         .__init__.py
     another\ 
         spam.py  #print('spam')
```

```
>>> import pkg

>>> pkg.__path__    #Only __path__[0] searched
   ['C:\\code\\pkg']    

>>> pkg.path.append(r'C:\another')

>>> pkg.__path__ 
   ['C:\\code\\pkg', 'C:\\another']   # __path__[1] omitted

>>> import pkg.spam                  # Fails! 
   ImportError:... 

>>> pkg.__path__.pop(0)              # Works!
>>> pkg.spam
    spam
```

So I'm wondering why Python only traverses `__path__[0]` rather than the whole list as it does in 3.X for namespace packages? It doesn't make sense to have `__path__` as list if it's not traversed fully. I know regular packages are different from namespace packages, but why bother having a list here and allowing only singe search path! However, Python 3.3 traverses the whole list which in some forms it emulates the behavior of namespace packages by adding directories in `__path__` attribute for a regular package.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behaviour in Python 2.6 and 2.7; all elements of `__path__` are searched there on python 2.6.9 and 2.7.9.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, you're correct and I've written the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__path__[0]` is not only the path that Python searched for relative imports within packages. At least this is a true behavior for what I tested in Cpython 2.7 and Python 3.3. Python traverses `__path__[0]` from left-to right when using relative imports. The role that `__path__[0]` list plays is the same role of `sys.path`. Both of them contains system paths (prefixes of directories) that lead to a package or a module which Python gleans automatically when using any of the import statement (e.g. `import`, `from`)

Indeed, you can extend the `__path__[0]` using `pkgutil.extend_path` function to let the relative package imports, import from different directories other than the package's directory. For example:

```
C:
  \dir0        #container directory
     \pkg      #package 
       __init__.py 
       spam.py
    \dir1 
        ham.py
>>> __path__ 
   ['C:\\dir0']
```

Assume that the `__init__.py` file (the initialization file) contain the following piece of code:

```
__path__.append(r'C:\\dir1')    #Or pkgutil.extend_path function
from . import spam,ham          #Relative import(relative to pkg dir)
```

`spam` will be imported from the package's directory since this is a **relative import** in both 2.X and 3.X. But, note how `ham` will also be imported successfully, even though it doesn't live within the package's home directory like `spam` module does, it still can be imported as the directory of the module `ham` in the `__path__` list of the package `pkg`.

Since `ham` was imported automatically without any error this is an indication that Python traverses the `__path__` list for packages from left-right.

Though, you can think of `__path__` as `sys.path`, but `__path__` is used only for imports within packages.Python 2.X searches `__path__`, before `sys.path`. That's *relative-then absolute*. Python 3.X changed this to, *absolute-only*, unless you use the dot in `from` import statement, `from . import ...`, Python 3.X will always search the module search path.